# Use both values of dateRangeInput() to subset dataset in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have the shiny app below in which I want to subset a dataframe according to dates based on a `dateRangeInput()`. The issue is that I cannot use both of its values at the same time to subset my dataset and the plot displays nothing. I could accept an alternative.

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)

date<-c(as.Date("2020-09-15", "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2020-09-14", "%Y-%m-%d"),
        as.Date("2020-09-13", "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date("2020-09-12", "%Y-%m-%d"))
value<-c(5,6,7,8)
value2<-c(0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5)
df<-data.frame(date,value,value2)



ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard Demo"),
    dashboardSidebar(
        
        sidebarMenu(
            dateRangeInput('dateRange',
                           label = paste('Date range input'),
                           start = min(df$date)+1, end = max(df$date),
                           min = min(df$date), max = max(df$date),
                           separator = " - ", format = "dd/mm/yy",
                           startview = 'year'
            )
            
        )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
        plotlyOutput("plot")
    )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    output$plot<-renderPlotly({
        
        TATd <-subset(df, date>=input$dateRange[1]&date<=input$dateRange[2])
        
        # Minimal theme + blue fill color
        p<-ggplot(data=TATd, aes(x=date, y=value)) +
            geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="steelblue")+
            theme_minimal()+ labs(x = "Date of Specimen Collection",y="Total Tests per Day")
        ggplotly(p)
        
        
    })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Seems related to https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2703

Comment: so there is no solution?

Answer (score 0):

With your sample data, it fixed the issue to use same value for both `start` and `min` in `dateRangeInput` initialization

```
  dateRangeInput('dateRange',
                 label = paste('Date range input'),
                 start = min(df$date), end = max(df$date),
                 min = min(df$date), max = max(df$date),
                 separator = " - ", format = "dd/mm/yy",
                 startview = 'year'
  )

Package  Version
Rcpp     1.0.5
cellranger   1.1.0
compiler     4.0.2
pillar   1.4.6
later    1.1.0.1
tools    4.0.2
digest   0.6.25
viridisLite  0.3.0
jsonlite     1.7.1
lifecycle    0.2.0
tibble   3.0.3
gtable   0.3.0
pkgconfig    2.0.3
rlang    0.4.7
rstudioapi   0.11
crosstalk    1.1.0.1
yaml     2.2.1
fastmap  1.0.1
httr     1.4.2
withr    2.3.0
dplyr    1.0.2
sourcetools  0.1.7
htmlwidgets  1.5.2
generics     0.0.2
vctrs    0.3.4
grid     4.0.2
tidyselect   1.1.0
glue     1.4.2
data.table   1.13.0
R6   2.4.1
tidyr    1.1.2
purrr    0.3.4
magrittr     1.5
scales   1.1.1
promises     1.1.1
htmltools    0.5.0
ellipsis     0.3.1
mime     0.9
xtable   1.8-4
colorspace   1.4-1
httpuv   1.5.4
labeling     0.3
lazyeval     0.2.2
munsell  0.5.0
crayon   1.3.4


other attached packages:
[1] plotly_4.9.2.1       ggplot2_3.3.2        shinydashboard_0.7.1 shiny_1.5.0       

R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
```

Comment: does it work for you?cause I see no change. I still cant see the plot

Comment: strange it does not work for me even if I open it in browser

Comment: I have exactly the same versions

Comment: using RStudio on windows 10 pro 64bits

Comment: This code works fine.  Not sure what the problem is here.  Perhaps you need to reboot your PC or restart RStudio.